# Information about algorithm used by Terrain models

Tags: qgis, grass-gis, slope, curvature, aspect

I have calculated slope and aspect using the DEM (Terrain models) GUI in QGIS Essen. I was also able to calculate the profile and tangential curvature using the toolbox r.slope.aspect. I was wondering if anyone can point me in the direction of documentation that describes the algorithm used to calculate these terrain parameters. I would like to know HOW they are calculated not how to use the plugins. For example, I would like to now how large of an averaging window the program uses, how it choses direction, what it does on the edges of a raster, etc.

Answer (score 6):

There is good documentation on all aspects of GRASS internals, including references to literature. So see the documentation on [r.slope.aspect](https://grass.osgeo.org/grass70/manuals/r.slope.aspect.html). Unfortunately I find it difficult to get this level of documentation for the methods exposed in the DEM/Terrain Models QGIS GUI. I'd recommend sticking entirely to GRASS if these implementation details are important to you; but perhaps someone else has a link to the QGIS implementation, it's probably all documented in GDAL.

Comment: If one is really keen and inquisitive, it can often be found in the source code, hence open source; for both GRASS and QGIS, GDAL, etc.

Comment: Agreed, but GRASS's comprehensive summaries of higher-level information is a big mark in its favour.

Comment: For sure, that's why I just added a comment. I've found GRASS manual pages and the wiki extremely educational.

Comment: As an extra, there are now the direct links to the source code starting from GRASS GIS 7.2.0 :-) See e.g. at page bottom of https://grass.osgeo.org/grass72/manuals/r.slope.aspect.html

Comment: There is great documentation of all GIS processing in a book entitled 'Geomorphometry: Concepts, Software, Applications' from the Developments in Soil Science series (33). I've found it to be very informative and helpful!